# how to disable firefox safe mode? (shift hotkey)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

Up until firefox 39 you could disable shift-click safe mode by creating a small set of files that sat in distribution/bundles in the install folder. as of Firefox 40 there is no distribution/bundles anymore (apparently). is there any other way to do this now? or, alternatively, a way to start safe-mode with add-ons still enabled? this is really important to me because of parental control

I've also considered finding a program that can disable Shift+click in my OS. I dont think anything like that exists though

hoping someone can help, ty

Comment: Wow this is interesting, I have never been able to get firefox to run in safe mode and have addons enabled.

Comment: Well, I downgraded back to Firefox 38. It's the ESR version but it's not gonna last  much more. Guess I'll have to rock an outdated FF.  I use a time-control extension (Leechblock) as well as a few others (FoxFilter), Website Block.  Very few programs I've used have had options like LB does. It can let you use a site for a few min a day, or in certain times of day. Meanwhile other programs just block things, period. However safe-mode can bypass it. Fortunately the distribution/bundles trick is a trick you can use to disable safe-mode. This trick no longer works in FF40+. guess i'm going retro